# Discretization of Kullback-Leibler Divergence

Tags: r, kullback-leibler, grid-approximation

I have a question regarding the Kullback-Leibler divergence. I am working on a project, in which we compare numerically distributions: the empirical distribution of the data compared to an approximate distribution. To measure the divergence, I use the Kullback-Leibler divergence. I've noted that I get negative KL-divergences, which should not be possible (proof [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/kl-nonneg2.html)) - so I started looking.

I evaluate both distributions numerically on a grid. So far, I thought that this grid can be arbitrarily designed but I ensure that the maximum and the minimum value of the observed realizations is covered. Since I am also working with heavy-tailed distributions, I wanted to have a grid with more grid elements in the center of the distribution. But as soon as I start to deviate from a linear spaced grid (i.e., meaning the distance between the grid elements is linear), the KL turns negative. I'll append a code in R to replicate the issue. See here:

```
set.seed(100)

# dimensions
ngrid     = 100  # number of grid elements
ndraws    = 1000 # number of draws
type_grid = "nonlinear"

# create draws from RV
X = rnorm(ndraws, 3, 0.3)
Y = rnorm(ndraws, 3, 0.3)

if(type_grid == "linear"){
  # define grid linear
  xgrid = seq(min(X,Y), max(X,Y), length.out=ngrid) # linear
}else if(type_grid == "nonlinear"){
  # define grid with more mass in the middle
  tmp_dens = density(c(X,Y))
  xgrid = sample(c(X,Y), ngrid, replace=TRUE) + tmp_dens$bw*rnorm(ngrid)
}

# kernel density estimator
fit.dens.X = density(X)
fit.dens.Y = density(Y)

# approximation at grid points
p.X = approx(fit.dens.X$x, fit.dens.X$y, xout = xgrid)$y
p.Y = approx(fit.dens.Y$x, fit.dens.Y$y, xout = xgrid)$y
p.X[is.na(p.X)] = 1e-100
p.Y[is.na(p.Y)] = 1e-100

# kullback-leibler divergence
sum(p.X * (log(p.X/p.Y)))
```

Any ideas why this is happing or how I can circumvent this? Specifically for heavy-tailed distributions it would be nice to deviate from a linear-spaced grid. Thanks in advance.